# Looping through a collection and deleting things on the way

Tags: loops, for-loop, julia

I want to go through a collection and find the first pair of matching elements, but my current approach is having trouble with the indexing going out of bounds all the time.

Here's a simplified MWE example:

```
function processstuff(stuff)
    for pointer1 in 1:length(stuff)
        for pointer2 in pointer1:length(stuff)
            println("$(stuff)")
            pointer1 == pointer2 && continue
            if stuff[pointer1] == stuff[pointer2]
                # items match, remove them
                deleteat!(stuff, pointer1)
                deleteat!(stuff, pointer2)
            end
        end
    end
end

processstuff(collect(rand(1:5, 20)))

[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1]
ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 16-element Array{Int64,1} at index [17]
```

(Obviously this example is just comparing two numbers, the real comparison isn't.)

The idea of updating the collection of stuff by removing both elements that have been processed looks like it works, because I think Julia updates the iteration thing each time through. But only for a while...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach (assuming you want to remove pairs):

```
function processstuff!(stuff)
    pointer1 = 1
    while pointer1 < length(stuff)
        for pointer2 in pointer1+1:length(stuff)
            if stuff[pointer1] == stuff[pointer2]
                deleteat!(stuff, (pointer1, pointer2))
                pointer1 -= 1 # correct pointer location as we later add 1 to it
                break
            end
        end
        pointer1 += 1
    end
end
```

In your code there were several problems:

- you called `deleteat!` twice, which could invalidate indexing
- your inner loop tried to delete `pointer1` several times
- in outer loop I use `while` to dynamically track changing size of `stuff`

Comment: The maestro strikes again! Thanks you so much, I see now that there are subtle aspects of the algorithm I hadn’t noticed.